# Cosmos db continuation token with order by creation date

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

**Goal:**

1. Query the orders in order of creation date.
2. Query max of 10 orders a time.

**Data type:** Partitioned by `/customerId`,

```
{
        "id": "2021-08-09-KX",
        "createdOn": 1628497893091,
        "estimatedAmount": 4200,
        "customerName": "NamPower",
        "customerId": "2131312",
        "activeStage": "Sales order",
        "status": {
            "value": "Pending SO",
            "type": "warning"
        },
        
},
```

**Challenge:** When I used the partition key for a specific customer, then it works. But I also want to be able to query all the orders .i.e without using a specific partition key. How can I achieve this? How can I remodel my data to achieve this?

```
async getAll(token?: string, limit = 10) {
    const querySpec = {
      query: "SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c.createdOn DESC",
    };

    const {
      resources: items,
      continuationToken,
      hasMoreResults,
    } = await this.dbContainer.items
      .query<IOrder>(querySpec, {
        maxItemCount: limit,
        // partitionKey: "2131312",
        continuationToken: token,
      })
      .fetchNext();
    this.store.order.load(items);
    return { hasMoreResults, continuationToken };
  }
```

Comment: Are you running into any issues with the code? Please edit your question and provide that. Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: @Gaurav The continuation token is returned but it doesn't return the next items. It not possible to do that as its [cross partition query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-pagination)

Comment: Please see this thread on Twitter: https://twitter.com/gmantri/status/1434551588966731791. HTH.